# How to recreate a sqlite database in ionic v3?

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I am using sqlite with ionic v3. Problem is that when i delete the sqlite db and recreate it will throw an error `No such table table1`.

```
this.sqlite.deleteDatabase({
        name: 'db.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
       .then(() => {
           return this.sqlite.create({
             name: 'db.db',
             location: 'default'
           })
       })
       .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        // create table queries
       });
```

Comment: Why you need to delete db i look they are same

Comment: I want to wipe out all the data.

Comment: actually best practices is if you delete table

Comment: If I delete and recreate all the tables then the problem is that previous data exist until I close the app from the background and reopen. In my app, I want to delete all the data on logout and recreate on login.

Comment: First of all you need to create service for table for all type of database operation then when you want to logout then drop table by services.

Comment: I am using service for db operations.

Answer (score 0):

becasuse of you only create the database. you need to create table after  creating database

your code looks like this way

```
this.sqlite.deleteDatabase({
        name: 'db.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
       .then(() => {
           return this.sqlite.create({
             name: 'db.db',
             location: 'default'
           })
       })
       .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        // create table queries
             db.executeSql('create table table1(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
            .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
         }); 
       });
```